# How to place html css php in javascript (Jquery)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this loop data in javascript. And i want to place html css and php for each value.

```
        var html = '';
              $.each(data, function(name, value) {
                 html += value.email + "<br />" + value.content + "<br />";
              });
              $('#sidebarColumn').html(html);
```

Here i just listed out some values. Lets say i want to have

```
<span class="userEmail">value.email<span>
<div class="userContent">value.content</div>
<img src="<?php echo base_url() ?> value.picture" />
```

How can i place them in JS or there is alternative way to make code readable?

Note*  i using .html() here because i want to replace #sidebarColumn previous data and place  the loop data in that div

Comment: If you want readable code and do a lot of this kind of rendering, you should check out a template engine, such as mustache: http://mustache.github.com/

Comment: <?php echo base_url() ?> is replaced server-side so will be of no use anyways. +1 for template solution.

Comment: @HollyStyles i need it because  value.picture is a path retrieve from db so it actually just something like this  public/images/abc.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write php in <script> tags like this, if that is what you are looking for

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var baseUrl = '<?php echo $this->baseUrl() ?>';

    var someVariable = '<?php 
                            //some more php here 
                        ?>'; 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
var html = '';
$.each(data, function(name, value) {

html += '<span class="userEmail">'+value.email+'<span>';
html += '<div class="userContent">'+value.content+'</div>';
html += '<img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>"' + value.picture + '/>';
});
$('#sidebarColumn').html(html);
```